# using mime to read hidden extension in links

Tags: php

I wanna crawl some academic search engine, for example this : http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=internet&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=
I wanna get the title, the url address of data that has pdf file only.
here's the code :

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = 'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=internet&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=';
$html = file_get_html($url) or die ('');
foreach($html->find('h3[class=gs_rt] a') as $link1){
    foreach($link1->parent()->parent()->parent()->find('div[class=gs_md_wp]') as $link2){
        $docLink = $link2->first_child();
        $link = $docLink->href;
        $mime = mime_content_type($link);  
        if ($mime == 'application/pdf'){
           $title   = strip_tags($link1->plaintext);echo $title;
           $webLink = strip_tags($link1->href);echo $webLink;
           $pdfLink = strip_tags($link);echo $link;
        }
    }
}
```

but I get warning `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type() in D:\AppServ\www\ekstension\try3.php on line 10`.

fyi, I've activated `extension=php_mime_magic.dll` in php.ini. what's wrong ? thanks

Comment: *"This function has been deprecated as the PECL extension [Fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) provides the same functionality (and more) in a much cleaner way"*